# How can I disable all my unchecked boxes on pageload?

Tags: jquery

When my page is loaded I wish all my unchecked boxes to be disabled:

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I tried it with this code, but it is not working:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        if($(".test").is(':checked'))
            $(".test").attr("disabled", false);
        else
            $(".test").attr("disabled", true);
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m7ny2Le7/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **[`:not(:checked)`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** to filter unchecked checkboxes

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(":checkbox:not(:checked)").prop('disabled', true)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked>I have a car
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Also you can use **[`prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/)** with callback

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(":checkbox").prop('disabled', function() {
    return !this.checked;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked>I have a car
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**NOTE :** In your code I can't see `test` class , so I'm using **[`:checkbox`](https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)** to refer all checkbox.

Comment: @PranavCBalan: Jarla got the `test` class in the jsfiddle. @Jarla: by using the selector `$(".test")` you are always addressing all elements with the class `test` and can't distinct between checked or unchecked checkboxes.

Comment: @Pekka : also problem with `$(".test").is(':checked')`

Comment: @PranavCBalan please enlighten me about `$(".test").is(':checked')` thank you

Comment: @Pekka :  as per jQuery documentation of is() : `Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.`

Comment: @PranavCBalan: Ah thank you! I understand. In your code with `$(":checkbox")` you are talking to all checkboxes on the page. I thought with `$(".test")` I am talking to all checkboxes with the class `test`

Comment: @Pekka the main problem with `$(".test").is(':checked')` is that the selector `$(".test")` returns all elements with the class `test`. you can't check multiple elements at once - you would need `$(".test").each(function(){})` to iterate over each single element with the class `test`.

Comment: @low_rents yeah that one i know thank you for additional info though it will help others

Answer (score 3):

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/m7ny2Le7/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").find('.test').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
            $(this).attr("disabled", false);
        else
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    });
});
```

Use `.each` to go through all the checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Simply select all of the unchecked checkboxes by using [:not](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) then set them to disabled:

```
 $('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true);
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m7ny2Le7/6/)

Answer (score 1):

`.test` is class so you want to iterate through elements with that class:

```js
$(".test").each(function() {
  $(this).prop("disabled", $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" class="test">I have a bike
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked class="test">I have a car
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Or even simpler `$(".test:checked").prop("disabled", true);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works. You have to iterate

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".test").each(function(){

            if($(this).is(':checked')){

                $(this).attr("disabled", false);
            } else {
                $(this).attr("disabled", true);
            }
        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution: https://jsfiddle.net/m7ny2Le7/4/

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("input[name='vehicle']").attr("disabled", true);

        if($("input[name='vehicle']:checked").length > 0)
            $("input[name='vehicle']:checked").attr("disabled", false); 
    });
```